# Gzip data to be sent to browser in php

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers

I want to Gzip data(css,js) being sent to browser in php . I tried [**gzcompress**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php),  [**gzencode**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php) but both made the file unrecognizable by the browser

Data from firebug for home.css

```
Date    Sat, 10 Sep 2011 22:31:59 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
Expires Sat, 17 Sep 2011 22:31:59 GMT
Cache-Control   public
Pragma  no-cache
Etag    e35b61f80bbf8e0dd722c50c65ec6da5
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  25163
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=92
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/css
```

EDIT: I even tried below that too didn't work

```
<?php 
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
 ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); 
else 
ob_start(); 
?>
```

Comment: the code you used could prove helpful, probably something wrong with the headers

Comment: `ob_gzhandler` already inspects the Accept-Encoding header to determine how the output should be encoded, you don't need to do this yourself.

Comment: The headers you posted basically look correct (they include the proper Content-Encoding and Vary headers). It's possible your output is already being compressed at the Apache level, so you're double-encoding by also doing it in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [appropriate headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) in order for the browser to recognize the file as being compressed.

This really however is a better task for your web server to handle, rather than your code.

Comment: @Web Developer "i didnt get anything" What

Comment: i mean the content of the link. The content of the link went over my head

Comment: The website didn't load? You didn't understand? You tried it and it doesn't work? What are you trying to say?

Comment: The content of the link went over my head

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
echo file_get_contents("stylesheet.css");
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php

just tested this with apache, if this isnt working for you you messed something up in your apache config.

headers:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:180
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sat, 10 Sep 2011 23:11:18 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.5
```